# Dynamically added Datepicker adds date to first field only

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page getInformation.php where I am populating a table. The code is as follows.

```
$i=1;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){ 
           if($row['Diag'] == '1' && $row['Treat']=='1'){
            $a = 'Something';
            echo '  
                                         <tr>  
                                              <td>'.$i.'</td>  
                                              <td><a href="http://www.google.com">'.$row['Name'].'</td>  
                                              <td>'.$a.'</td>  
                                              <td><input class="datepicker" id="date" name="date'.$i.'" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text"/></td>  
                                              <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lsm active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Accpet</a></td> 
                                              <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lsm active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Reject</a></td> 
                                         </tr>  
                                         ';

                              $i++;
           }
           if($row['Diag'] == '0' && $row['Treat']=='1'){
            $a = 'Treat';
            echo '  
                                         <tr>  
                                              <td>'.$i.'</td>  
                                              <td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>  
                                              <td>'.$a.'</td>  
                                              <td><input class="datepicker" id="date" name="date'.$i.'" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text"/></td>  
                                              <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lsm active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Accpet</a></td> 
                                              <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lsm active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Reject</a></td> 
                                         </tr>  
                                         ';

                                $i++;
                            }

          }
```

The problem is that when I select any date field, it updates the value to the first date field only. No matter which date field i select. For example, I have 4 rows, and if I select the 4th row's date field, only the 1st row's field gets populated.

My javascript code is follows:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

$(document).on("focus", ".datepicker", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
     // $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
   });
});
</script>
```

Any input will be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html id's should be unique. Do the same as u do with name :

```
id="date'.$i.'"
```

Comment: Thanks! That was simple. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through all elements with class `datepicker`

```
$('.datepicker').each(function( index ) {
    /* Do something with the element */
});
```

> Manual: https://api.jquery.com/each/